# Game character sprite positioning and movement

Tags: optimization, beginner, design-patterns, actionscript-3

The player will have different spells that can be cast on different keyboard key combinations.

Right now what I have is one .as file with everything on it. A bunch of `if`s, checking for combos `if (combo="WW") {}`, `if (flightMode) {}` and so on, which I know is bad practice and makes it confuse.

There will be more combos/different key combinations so I need to start learning neatness.

I'm looking for code correctness and best practices.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

import nape.geom.Vec2;
import nape.phys.Body;
import nape.phys.BodyList;
import nape.phys.BodyType;
import nape.shape.Polygon;
import nape.space.Space;
import nape.util.ShapeDebug;

public class Main extends Sprite 
{       
    public var gravity:Number = 600;

    public var space:Space = new Space(new Vec2(0, gravity));
    public var antiGravity:Vec2 = new Vec2(0, -gravity);
    public var impulse:Vec2 = new Vec2(0, 0);
    public var flight:Vec2 = new Vec2(0, 0);

    public var mainChar:Body = new Body(BodyType.DYNAMIC);

    public var allow2ndKey:Boolean;
    public var allow3rdKey:Boolean;
    public var combo:String;
    public var spellTimerStart:Boolean;
    public var heroPosition:Boolean = true;
    public var heroFlightMode:Boolean = false;
    public var flightModeMovement:Boolean = false;

    public var velChange:Number;
    public var desiredVel:Number = -1800;
    public var startingHeroY:Number;
    public var spellTimer:Number = 70;

    public var reset:Boolean = false;

    public var flyUp:Number;
    public var flyUpVel:Number = -150;
    public var Up:Boolean;
    public var Down:Boolean;
    public var flyDown:Number;
    public var flyDownVel:Number = 150;
    public var Right:Boolean;
    public var flyRight:Number;
    public var flyRightVel:Number = 125;
    public var Left:Boolean;
    public var flyLeft:Number;
    public var flyLeftVel:Number = -125;
    public var keys:Array = [];
    public var float:Number = 30;
    public var floatUp:Boolean = true;
    public var fallSTR:Number;
    public var fall:Vec2 = new Vec2(0, 0);
    public var exeOnce:Boolean=true;

    public var floor:Body;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        createMainCharacter(stage.stageWidth * 10 / 100, stage.stageHeight * 10 /100, 50, 50);
        createWall (0, 500, stage.stageWidth, 10);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);
    }

    private function update(e:Event):void 
    {
        space.step(1 / stage.frameRate, 10, 10);
        var bodies:BodyList = space.bodies;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) 
        {
            var body:Body=bodies.at(i);
            if (body.userData.sprite != null) 
            {
                body.userData.sprite.x = body.position.x;
                body.userData.sprite.y = body.position.y;
                body.userData.sprite.rotation=(body.rotation*180/Math.PI)%360;
            }
        }

        if (combo == "WW") 
        {
            if (heroPosition) {
                startingHeroY = mainChar.position.y;
            }
            heroPosition = false;
            velChange = desiredVel - mainChar.velocity.y;           
            impulse.x = 0.0;
            impulse.y = velChange;
            mainChar.applyImpulse(impulse);
            if (mainChar.position.y <= startingHeroY - 1) {
                desiredVel = -55;
            }
        }

        if (combo == "WWW") 
        {
            heroFlightMode = true;
            reset = true;
        }

        if (heroFlightMode) 
        {
            velChange = -mainChar.velocity.y-float;
            antiGravity.x = 0.0;
            antiGravity.y = velChange;
            mainChar.applyImpulse(antiGravity);
            flightModeMovement = true;
            if (float == 30) {
                floatUp = true;
            }

            if (float == 65) {
                floatUp = false;
            }

            if (floatUp) {
                float++;
            } else {float--;}

        } else flightModeMovement = false;

        if (flightModeMovement) {
            if (keys[Keyboard.W]) 
            {
                flyUp = -mainChar.velocity.y - 400; // flyUpVel - mainChar.velocity.y;
                flight.x = 0.0;
                flight.y = flyUp;
                mainChar.applyImpulse(flight);
            }

            if (keys[Keyboard.S]) 
            {
                flyDown = flyDownVel - mainChar.velocity.y;
                flight.x = 0.0;
                flight.y = flyDown;
                mainChar.applyImpulse(flight);
            }

            if (keys[Keyboard.D]) 
            {
                flyRight = flyRightVel - mainChar.velocity.x;
                flight.x = flyRight;
                flight.y = 0.0;
                mainChar.applyImpulse(flight);
            }

            if (keys[Keyboard.A]) 
            {
                flyLeft = flyLeftVel - mainChar.velocity.x; // flyLeftVel = -3
                flight.x = flyLeft;
                flight.y = 0.0;
                mainChar.applyImpulse(flight);
            }

            if (keys[Keyboard.SPACE]) 
            {
                heroFlightMode = false;
            }
        }

        if (spellTimerStart) {
            spellTimer--;
        } else spellTimer = 70;

        if (spellTimer <= 0) {
            reset = true;
            if (exeOnce) {
                fallSTR = 500;
                fall.x = 0.0;
                fall.y = fallSTR;
                mainChar.applyImpulse(fall);
            }
            exeOnce = false;

        }

        if (reset) 
        {
            // reset everything
            combo = "null";
            allow2ndKey = false;
            allow3rdKey = false;
            spellTimerStart = false;
            heroPosition = true;
            spellTimer = 70;
            desiredVel = -1200;
            startingHeroY = 0;
            reset = false;
        }

    } // update end.

    private function createWall (x:Number, y:Number, width:Number, height:Number):void
    {
        var wall:Body = new Body(BodyType.STATIC);
            wall.shapes.add(new Polygon(Polygon.rect(x, y, width, height)));
        var wallSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            wallSprite.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            wallSprite.graphics.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
            wallSprite.graphics.endFill;
        addChild(wallSprite);   

        wall.userData.sprite = wallSprite;
        addChild(wall.userData.sprite);

        wall.space = space;
    }

    private function createMainCharacter(x:Number, y:Number, width:Number, height:Number):void 
    {
        var mainCharShape:Polygon = new Polygon(Polygon.box(width, height));

        mainChar.shapes.add(mainCharShape);
        mainChar.position.setxy(x, y);
        mainChar.space = space;

        var mainCharSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            mainCharSprite.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            mainCharSprite.graphics.drawRect( -width/2, -height/2, width, height);
            mainCharSprite.graphics.endFill;
        addChild(mainCharSprite);

        mainChar.userData.sprite = mainCharSprite;
        addChild(mainChar.userData.sprite);
    }

    public function onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {
        keys[e.keyCode] = false;
        if (spellTimerStart) {
            allow2ndKey = true;
        }

    }

    public function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {
        keys[e.keyCode] = true;

        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
            case Keyboard.W:
                if (!flightModeMovement) {
                        spellTimerStart = true;
                        exeOnce = true;
                        combo = "W";
                        if (allow3rdKey && spellTimer) {
                            combo = "WWW";
                            spellTimer = 70;
                        } else {
                        if (allow2ndKey && spellTimer > 0)
                        {
                            combo = "WW";
                            spellTimer += 50;
                            allow2ndKey = false;
                            allow3rdKey = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            break
        }
    }

} // Class end
} // package end
```

How could I optimize this? I have no experience with custom classes.

Comment: Please show more code. Right now my answer would be wholly incomplete in regards to your question. In particular, don't replace the reset content with a comment. I'd also like to see the update function. Because right now I'm struggling to understand how a combo works (and whether there are any bugs in your implementation). In fact, you say you have 1 `.as` file with everything on it - just post the entire file, and we'll help you split it up to classes.

Comment: K wait, I'm editing now

Comment: It's good to be copied now. Instructions: Pressing W will start a counter, if still within time you press W again it will go up in the air and hover for a bit. When time runs out it will fall. Pressing W a 3rd time though will make it "lose" gravity and controlable in air. Space Bar to make it fall and reset.

Comment: Right, now I can actually see the scale of the problem. Before, I would have written 2 paragraphs and that'd be it. I'll take a better look at your question if I can do so today (roughly 6-8 hours from now).

Answer (score 3):

### Single Responsibility Principle

"A class should have one, and only one, reason to change." (defined in [The Principles of OOD](http://www.butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod))
You can use this principle to group parts of the code that have the same reason to change into classes. Imagine what changes you would need to make in order to add a new player spell or a new key combo, for example, then extract those into a class.

On the other hand, if you end up changing a class for more than one reason, then that class should be split into several classes with different reasons to change.

Comment: I had read that before. I did thought of making a class for spells as there is the combo, the name and timing. function Spell() {}, function keyCombo(){}, function timer(){}. But that's all I got, hopefully with a few tip-answers I'll get to it. I'm on it.

Comment: Your classes don't absolutely have to model the "real world" objects, but that's not a bad start either.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables

```
public var Up:Boolean;
public var Down:Boolean;
public var Right:Boolean;
public var Left:Boolean;
```

are unused. I think this is because you've stuffed everything in one class. If you use multiple classes (via SRP, as Kolargol00 says), you'll have smaller classes and it will be easier to find these unused variables.

Specifically, I'd make a class for Keyboard input, a class for the hero character, and a class for a wall to start with.